# How to use openldap with fabric-ca in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: docker, ldap, hyperledger-fabric, openldap, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to use openldap docker container with fabric-ca , I've been searching on internet for a week now. Is there anyone in the community who have tried or implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have done it myself, but you can configure the Fabric CA to use LDAP.

Inside your [CA Server Configuration file](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serverconfig.html) there is a section related to LDAP. More specifically, you would start by enabling LDAP and pointing to the URL where it is running:

```
ldap:
   enabled: true
   url: ldap://<adminDN>:<adminPassword>@<host>:<port>/<base>
```

If you have enabled TLS using self-signed certificates on the LDAP server then you would need to also configure TLS to trust the signing certificate.

The Fabric CA documentation has [a section](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#configuring-ldap) on how you would configure LDAP, see that for more elaborate configurations. It includes the minimum configuration that you would need to do to get started with using OpenLDAP Docker container `osixia/openldap`:

```
ldap:
   enabled:    true
   url:        ldap://cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org:admin@localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=org
   userfilter: (uid=%s)
```

Finally, [this Medium](https://medium.com/@aleksobol/hyperledger-fabric-with-ldap-integration-part-1-81c787dd78e0) post discusses the steps needed to configure Fabric CA to use LDAP. I believe the author is using OpenLDAP. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your response. I went through this tutorial but in this he has shown how to use LDAP server , he is not using openldap container. The above thing i know that i 've to do but i 've never worked on ldap servers. I want to know do i have to create a schema for the certificates  ? not sure what to do on the LDAP side.

Comment: Since the Fabric CA Documentation mentions osixia/openldap container, perhaps you can look at the GitHub page for it for configuring the LDAP side: https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

Comment: this didn't work as you suggested, lots of errors and bugs with this openldap docker image. 
Is there anyone, who has tried solving it ?