# How to integrate openldap with Hyperledger fabric CA for enrolling and registering users?

Tags: ldap, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, openldap, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to move my application to production level and i have no clue how to proceed. I've searched the whole internet but couldn't findy anything that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use openldap with fabric-ca in hyperledger fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904503/how-to-use-openldap-with-fabric-ca-in-hyperledger-fabric)